# Is it possible to download YouTube videos with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm looking at being able to download YouTube videos within a React Native app created with Expo. I'm currently using Expo's [FileSystem.downloadAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemdownloadasyncuri-fileuri-options), however this requires a direct URL to the resource to download. I've come across quite a few packages such as [youtube-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl) but they all require Node.JS to run.

My next thought was to use Node.JS within my app using [nodejs-mobile](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile) - until I found out that you need to eject from Expo, which I definitely don't want to do.

Does anyone know of a way to download a YouTube video within an Expo app? Or just simply get a direct file link to pass into [FileSystem.downloadAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemdownloadasyncuri-fileuri-options)?

Comment: You can use external web services with simple http get like https://download-api.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use [react-native-ytdl](https://github.com/AbelTesfaye/react-native-ytdl) to get the direct video URL via their `getInfo` method ([see this example](https://github.com/AbelTesfaye/react-native-ytdl/issues/9#issuecomment-515678955)) and then still use `FileSystem.downloadAsync` to download the file(s).

Since no linking is required, you wouldn't need to eject.

Comment: Would you potentially know of any other libraries that do this? Been trying to use this one all day however stuck in callbacks.

Comment: This one looks like the best bet to me. I found a few libraries that would require ejecting, which personally I don't think is such a big deal in terms of added complexity. Depends on your limitations and goals though. Otherwise I'd consider using an external Node.js server to fetch and (temporarily) store the file for your mobile app to download it.

Comment: Was able to get it working based off an answer on Github https://github.com/AbelTesfaye/react-native-ytdl/issues/12